# Reverse vowels in a given string, take the upper/lower case into account

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Given a text string, create and return a new string constructed by finding all its vowels (for
simplicity, in this problem vowels, are the letters in the string "aeiouAEIOU") and reversing their
order, while keeping all non-vowel characters exactly as they were in their original positions.
However, to make the result look prettier, the capitalization of each vowel must be the same as that
of the vowel originally in that same position. For example, reversing the vowels of "Ilkka" should
produce "Alkki" instead of "alkkI"

My code works if I do not take into account the matter of if the vowel is upperCase originally. However, when I take that into account somehow my consonants also start messing around

```py
def reverse_vowels(s):
    vowels = set(list("aeiouAEIOU"))
    s = list(s)
    ptr_1, ptr_2 = 0, len(s) - 1
    while ptr_2 > ptr_1:
        if s[ptr_1] in vowels and s[ptr_2] in vowels:
            print("ptr_1: " + str(ptr_1) + " ,s[ptr_1]: " + s[ptr_1] + "; ptr_2: " + str(ptr_2) + " ,s[ptr_2]: " + s[ptr_2])
            if str(s[ptr_1]).isupper() and str(s[ptr_2]).islower():
                s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2].upper(), s[ptr_1].lower()
                ptr_1 += 1
                ptr_2 -= 1
            if str(s[ptr_2]).isupper() and str(s[ptr_1]).islower():
                s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2].lower(), s[ptr_1].upper()
                ptr_1 += 1
                ptr_2 -= 1
            s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2], s[ptr_1]
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1

        elif s[ptr_1] not in vowels:
            ptr_1 += 1
        elif s[ptr_2] not in vowels:
            ptr_2 -= 1
        else:
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1
    return ''.join(s)
```

Expected result: reverse_vowels("HEllo world") = "HOllo werld"
Actual result: "HOwlo lerld"

Comment: Please take time to go through the intro tour.  As it says in a couple of places, "make it easy for others to help you."  Undocumented code using generic variable names is *not* easy to follow, especially with redundant code inserted.  Next time ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make any sort of logic diagram (such as a flowchart) before you updated the code?  You've tied your logic into a bit of a knot.

The simplest observation is here:

```
        if str(s[ptr_1]).isupper() and str(s[ptr_2]).islower():
            s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2].upper(), s[ptr_1].lower()
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1
        if str(s[ptr_2]).isupper() and str(s[ptr_1]).islower():
            s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2].lower(), s[ptr_1].upper()
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1
        s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2], s[ptr_1]
        ptr_1 += 1
        ptr_2 -= 1
```

If the vowels differ in case, you swap them, update the pointers, and *then* you swap again, *regardless* of the case.  This is where your consonants get involved, because the pointers have moved off the vowels you identified.  Simply clean up that logic flow into the three cases I *hope* you intended:

```
        if str(s[ptr_1]).isupper() and str(s[ptr_2]).islower():
            s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2].upper(), s[ptr_1].lower()
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1
        elif str(s[ptr_2]).isupper() and str(s[ptr_1]).islower():
            s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2].lower(), s[ptr_1].upper()
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1
        else:
            s[ptr_1], s[ptr_2] = s[ptr_2], s[ptr_1]
            ptr_1 += 1
            ptr_2 -= 1
```

Output:

```
ptr_1: 1 ,s[ptr_1]: E; ptr_2: 7 ,s[ptr_2]: o
HOllo werld
```

---

I strongly recommend that you re-examine your logic flow.  Most of all, you update your pointers in *six* places, when you have only three distinct cases to consider.  If you haven't been taught how to make a flowchart or other logic diagram, I recommend that you pick a method that suits you and teach yourself.  You can unravel a lot of these problems with such visual aids.

Comment: Thank you! I should have sorted the knot by making a logic diagram.

Answer (score 0):

A funny way to solve the exercice using the format function :

```
def reverse_vowels(s):
    vowels = set(list("aeiouAEIOU"))
    s_vowels = []
    s_vowels_upper = []
    result = ""

    for c in s:
        if c in vowels:
            result += "{}"
            s_vowels.append(c)
            s_vowels_upper.append(c==c.upper())
        else:
            result+=c

    s_vowels_reversed = [c.upper() if s_vowels_upper[i] else c.lower() 
                         for i,c in enumerate(s_vowels[::-1])]

    return result.format(*s_vowels_reversed)
```

Results :

```
>>> reverse_vowels("HEllo world")
'HOllo werld'
>>> reverse_vowels("Ilkka")
'Alkki'
```

Comment: Thank you! What an elegant solution compared to mine, kudos

Answer (score 0):

this worked :

```
def reverse_vowels(s):
    vowels = list("aeiouAEIOU")
    s = list(s)
    v = [] 
    for i in range(len(s)) : 
      if s[i] in vowels : 
        v.append(s[i])

    r = [i for i in reversed(v)]

    k = 0 

    for i in range(len(s)) : 
      if s[i] in vowels : 
        if s[i].isupper() : 
          s[i] = r[k].upper()
        else : 
          s[i] = r[k].lower()

        k = k + 1
    return ''.join(s)

print(reverse_vowels("HEllo world"))
```

output

```
HOllo werld
```

use the reversed function after getting the vowels in the string then put them back accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```py
def reverse_vowels(word):
    all_vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    vowels = []
    for char in word:
        if char.lower() in all_vowels:
            vowels.append(char.lower())

    new_word = ''
    for char in word:
        if char.lower() in all_vowels:
            vowel = vowels.pop(-1)
            if char.isupper():
                vowel = vowel.upper()

            new_word += vowel
        else:
            new_word += char

    return new_word
```

Input: HEllo world 
Output: HOllo werld

Answer (score 0):

As Corentin said, the format function can be useful in this situation

```py
my_string = "HEllo world"
vouels = list("aeiou")
upper_case_indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_string) if x.isupper()]
print upper_case_indexes
# output: [0, 1]

my_string_lower = my_string.lower()
my_reversed_vouels = [x for x in my_string_lower if x in vouels][::-1]
print my_reversed_vouels
# output: ['o', 'o', 'e']

replaced_vouels_list = map(lambda x: "{}" if x in vouels else x, my_string_lower)
print replaced_vouels_list
# output: ['h', '{}', 'l', 'l', '{}', ' ', 'w', '{}', 'r', 'l', 'd']

replaced_vouels_str = "".join(replaced_vouels_list)
print replaced_vouels_str
# output: h{}ll{} w{}rld

formated_str = replaced_vouels_str.format(*my_reversed_vouels)
print formated_str
# output: hollo werld

uppercase_str = "".join([x.upper() if i in upper_case_indexes else x for i, x in enumerate(list(formated_str))])
print uppercase_str
# output: HOllo werld
```